# P tag not rendering correctly in iBooks 2.0.1

Tags: epub, ibooks

I have an EPUB created with InDesign 5.5 and am trying to use the built-in Futura on the iPad. H1 and H2 tags render properly in iBooks 2.0.1 but P tag and classes default to Times Roman. I've tried the samp hack, but no luck. Here's an example:

```
p.Narrative-Body {
font-family : Futura, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight : normal;
font-style : normal;
font-size : 1em;
font-variant : normal;
line-height : 1.6;
text-align : left;
color : #000000; }
```

and here's the html:

```
<p class="Narrative-Body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sapien lorem, semper ac tempus quis, imperdiet quis dui. Morbi sed sollicitudin elit.</p> *Real copy covered by non-disclosure.*
```

Couldn't find any answers on the e-production sites and I re-installed iBooks. Same problem. However, it works properly in ADE and Safari and Calibre correctly shows sans-serif.
Thanks in advance!

---

We're making progress!! I added the com.apple xml file and mapped my body style to p tags. Now they display Futura, but only if they're straight p tags or p tags with spans (used for run-in text). P tags w/classes still don't use  Futura. Just as a test, I made the class names lowercase in the html and css, but still no luck. Here's the revised HTML:

```
<p><span class="Quote-RunIn">“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci.” </p>
```

The CSS is now:

```
p {
font-family: Futura, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 1em;
font-variant: normal;
line-height: 1.6;
text-align: left;
margin: 0 0 1em 0;
orphans: 2;
widows: 2;
```

}

Natasha, since I'm not using the samp tag, I should specify the font-family in the p tag, right?

Comment: have you tried removing the space between your attribute and the :.  "font-family:" instead of "font-family :"  I've never seen anyone write CSS like that before.

Comment: Is there some other style sheet involved that could set `font-family` for `p` elements?

Comment: Thanks both of you, but unfortunately these suggestions didn't work. @thenetimp InDesign 5.5 inserts that space before the colons when exporting to EPUB, don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the com.apple.ibooks.display-options.xml file in your META-INF? It should have in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<display_options>
<platform name="*">
<option name="specified-fonts">true</option>
</platform>
</display_options>
```

This might just be necessary for embedded fonts; I forget. I'm sorry, LOL! Let me know if that works for you!

---

That's right. The font-family doesn't work inside the p tag, although it works inside the h tags. You want to take out the font-family in the p tag. Do this:

```
p.Narrative-Body {
font-weight : normal;
font-style : normal;
font-size : 1em;
font-variant : normal;
line-height : 1.6;
text-align : left;
color : #000000; }
samp { font-family : Futura, Arial, sans-serif; }
```

The the markup should be:

```
<p class="Narrative-Body"><samp>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sapien lorem, semper ac tempus quis, imperdiet quis dui. Morbi sed sollicitudin elit.</samp></p>
```

Please note that you will also need the file I mentioned before in your META-INF folder.

This definitely works; if you find it doesn't, then maybe run through CSS and Markup validators, and see if there's something else interfering?

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Natasha, but unfortunately, it didn't help. I think that is just for embedded fonts.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need the Apple Display Options file in your META-INF with specified-fonts=true. This setting is for all specified fonts - both embedded and system.

p { font-family: Futura;} is fine syntax - it will work in iBooks.

If you have access to the iOS simulator, drag your XHTML file into Safari in the simulator and test there - its sometimes pickier about capitalization, etc. That said, the capitalized class is not a problem.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got it to work, thanks to all of you for your help. Adding the Apple Display Options file did the trick. I hope Adobe finds a way to generate this file automatically in future updates. I wound up leaving the font-family property in the p tag because that's how InDesign generated it. Since it was working, I figured, why tempt fate??

BTW, iBooks seems to honor img width tags in the latest version.

Answer (score -1):

says Derrick Schultz, @dvsch on twitter:

> Can't speak to ePub, but in HTML that wouldn't validate because classes need to start w/ lowercase letters.

Comment: That information is wrong: class names must start with a letter [a-zA-Z], but there are no restrictions on upper- or lowercase (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/22114).